# Switch between routers Express

Tags: node.js, express

I want to display a website completely different in function of an arbitrary value.

Let's say I have two routers

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router1 = express.Router();
router1.get('/', (req, res, next) => res.json({message: 'I am the router1'}))
const router2 = express.Router();
router2.get('/', (req, res, next) => res.json({message: 'I am the router2'}))
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
        // Use router1
    } else {
        // Use router2
    }
})
```

I have no idea how I can do that. I will have a lots of routes (`router.get`, `router.post`) I don't want to check that on each route

Thanks

Comment: Try `app.use('/', router1 or router2);` based on your condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return a call to the router:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
        return router1(req, res, next)
    } else {
        return router2(req, res, next)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done by usage of `.next('router')` method.

Here is an example:

```
const router1 = express.Router();

router1.use((req, res, next) => { 

  console.log("This gets called everytime!");

  if(Math.random() > 0.5) 
    next('router');//skip to next router object
  else
    next();//continue with current router
});

router1.get('/',(req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Continuing with current router");
  res.send("Continuing with current router");
});


const router2 = express.Router();

router2.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Skipped Router 1, continuing with router 2");
  res.send("Skipped Router 1, continuing with router 2");
});

//binding both routers here
app.use("*", router1, router2);
```

`.next('router')` basically skips to next router object, which has been mentioned in the `app.use` line, if only `next()` is used then it continues with current router methods.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just?

```
if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
    app.use(router1);
} else {
    app.use(router2);
}
```